# Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebChat]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebChat]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/json/JsonStructure  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMethodMapping.(PojoMethodMapping.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:234)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.json.JsonStructure  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     ... 15 more  Feb 14, 2017 10:04:34 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more  Feb 14, 2017 10:04:34 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start SEVERE: The required Server
>   component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more  Feb 14, 2017 10:04:34 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"] Feb 14, 2017 10:04:34 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] Feb 14, 2017 10:04:34 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
>   service Catalina Feb 14, 2017 10:04:34 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Feb 14, 2017 10:04:35 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a jar o java class is missing at run time. Did you check presence of javax.json-api-1.0.jar in your application? check if help
[Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)
more detail could be useful on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as the stack trace prints

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/JsonStructure
```

You need to add to your project sources `javax.json-api-1.0.jar`